Understanding the proof to a corollary of Gauss's lemma
I am trying to understand the proof of this corollary to Gauss's lemma found in Abstract Algebra (Theory and Applications) by Thomas W. Judson.
Here is the link to a screenshot of the proof 
What Gauss's Lemma says is that if one has a monic polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ that factors into two polynomials $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then there exist monic polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg \alpha(x) = \deg a(x)$ and $\deg \beta(x) = \deg b(x)$ such that $p(x) = a(x)b(x)$.
I understand that if $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a zero of $p(x)$, then $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$. The problem I have with understanding this proof is that the lemma doesn't say that the linear factor in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ must have the form $x-\alpha$. The general form for linear factors is $a'x+b$ for $a', b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, if I assume this, I can write
$$p(x) = (a'x+b)q(x),$$
where $\deg q(x) = n-1$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, I'm not assured that there exists $(a')^{-1}$ such that $a'(a')^{-1} = (a')^{-1}a = 1$, otherwise I would be able to write $p(x)= (x-\alpha )q'(x)$ where $\alpha = -b(a')^{-1}$ and $q'(x) = (a')^{-1}q(x)$. I'm aware of Monic polynomial reducible over rationals (Gauss's Lemma) but this doesn't say exactly why the linear factor has the form $x-\alpha$ instead of the usual $a'x+b$ for linear factors. Is the Polynomial Factor Theorem true over all commutative rings? discuss Factor Theorem's validity in arbitrary commutative rings, which I think is broader than want I'm asking.
I'd appreciate any explanations.

If you examine the proof of the original Gauss' lemma, it might (should) imply that the linear factor is in fact $x-\alpha$

I have examined the proof of the lemma and it does indeed imply that the linear factor has the form $x-\alpha$. Thank you.
